# Adding onClick event dynamically using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Due to a plugin being used, I can't add the "onClick" attribute to the HTML form inputs like usual.
A plugin is handling the forms part in my site and it doesn't give an option to do this automatically.

Basically I have this input:

```
<input type="text" id="bfCaptchaEntry" name="bfCaptchaEntry" style="">
```

I want to add an onClick to it with jQuery onload for it to be like this:

```
<input onClick="myfunction()" type="text" id="bfCaptchaEntry" name="bfCaptchaEntry" style="">
```

How do I go about doing this?

I know this might not be standard practice but seems like the easiest option to do in my situation.

I'm a newbie to jQuery so any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 270, accepted):

You can use the `click` event and call your function or move your logic into the handler:

```
$("#bfCaptchaEntry").click(function(){ myFunction(); });
```

You can use the `click` event and set your function as the handler:

```
$("#bfCaptchaEntry").click(myFunction);
```

---

**.click()**

> Bind an event handler to the "click" JavaScript event, or trigger that event on an element.

http://api.jquery.com/click/

---

You can use the `on` event bound to `"click"` and call your function or move your logic into the handler:

```
$("#bfCaptchaEntry").on("click", function(){ myFunction(); });
```

You can use the `on` event bound to `"click"` and set your function as the handler:

```
$("#bfCaptchaEntry").on("click", myFunction);
```

---

**.on()**

> Attach an event handler function for one or more events to the
>   selected elements.

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Simple and easy to understand. Exactly what I wanted.
Another question: what's the easiest way to integrate a background color change using jQuery? or is it better to use 'style.backgroundColor = "white";' in the function section?

Answer (score 71):

try this approach if you know your object client name ( it is not important that it is Button or TextBox )

```
$('#ButtonName').removeAttr('onclick');
$('#ButtonName').attr('onClick', 'FunctionName(this);');
```

try this ones if you want add onClick event to a server object with JQuery

```
$('#' + '<%= ButtonName.ClientID %>').removeAttr('onclick');
$('#' + '<%= ButtonName.ClientID %>').attr('onClick', 'FunctionName(this);');
```

Comment: This one sets the function, without calling it at the same time.

Comment: Using the .attr onClick instead of .click also means you can directly assign a script command instead of calling a function, like `"history.go(0);"` or `"alert('Hi!');"`.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, as I wanted to be able both define a separate function and be able to set the function without calling it. Thank you 4 years late.

Comment: What I love about this answer is that it doesn't call the function but only sets onclick

Answer (score 23):

Try below approach,

```
$('#bfCaptchaEntry').on('click', myfunction);
```

or in case jQuery is not an absolute necessaity then try below,

```
document.getElementById('bfCaptchaEntry').onclick = myfunction;
```

However the above method has few drawbacks as it set onclick as a property rather than being registered as handler...

Read more on this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/6348597/297641

Comment: When you say 'However the above method', it is not clear if you are refering just the plain javascript method `.onclick`, or grouping both versions as one in comparison to using `.click`. I know its actually the former, as `.on` does register the handler, but had to check elsewhere to learn that. It would be good for future readers if it was more clear in your answer... ;)

Answer (score 7):

```
$("#bfCaptchaEntry").click(function(){
    myFunction();
});
```

Answer (score 7):

Or you can use an arrow function to define it:

```
$(document).ready(() => {
  $('#bfCaptchaEntry').click(()=>{
    
  });
});
```

For better browser support:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#bfCaptchaEntry').click(function (){
    
  });
});
```

Comment: I don't see how this provides anything new as the accepted answer already suggested the `.click()` method. Whether to use arrow functions or regular functions is, in my opinion, a discussion not related to the question asked. And for better browser support you should probably remove both arrow functions, not only the first one.

Comment: Because is another way to use jQuery

Answer (score 3):

```
let a = $("<a>bfCaptchaEntry</a>");
a.attr("onClick", "function(" + someParameter+ ")");
```

Answer (score 1):

as @Selvakumar Arumugam suggested, but the function call on registering also

`$('#bfCaptchaEntry').on('click', myfunction);`,

rather than use

`$('#bfCaptchaEntry').on('click', () => { myfunction});`