# can not get the dom element after appending rows of table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I want to fetch the json data from serve and then loop the rows of table. the html code is like:

```
<table id="topics_list_table">
  <thead>
    <tr><th>Topic Title</th>
    <th>Author Name</th>
    <th>Likes</th>
    <th>Created Time</th>
    <th>Actions</th>
  </tr></thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

the jQuery part:

```
$.ajax({
            url: some url here,
            type:'GET',

            success:function(res){
                $.each(res, function(index, value){
                    $('#topics_list_table > tbody:last').
                    append(
                        "<tr>" +
                        "<td>" + value.title + "</td>"+
                        "<td>" + value.author_name + "</td>"+
                        "<td>" + value.likes + "</td>"+
                        "<td>" + value.created + "</td>"+
                        "<td>" +
                        "<a href='/components/topics/" + value.id + "' class='mini ui black buttons' id='detail_check'>check</a>"+
                        "</td>"+
                        "</tr>"
                    );
                });
            }
        });
```

I could get all the data from the remote side, but the key question is this part

```
<a href='/components/topics/" + value.id + "' class='mini ui black buttons' onclick='somefunction()'>check</a>
```

I inspect this page and found, sth like

```
<a href="/components/topics/53cf67fad0c0f7fdda3ef8d5" class="mini ui black buttons"  onclick='somefunction()'>check</a>
```

already exists in the dom.

but

1, the style class="mini ui black buttons" can not be applied.
2, when you try to click the "check" and want to trigger the somefunction(). it doesnt work.

so, why couldn't i get the dom element after appending the rows? OR, is there any other better way to loop rows after fetching the data?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onclick` attributes only work in the initial HTML, not in appended elements. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12284168/adding-onclick-event-dynamically-using-jquery).

Instead, add the event handler using [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click) or [`.on('click')`](http://api.jquery.com/on):

```
       success:function(res){
            $.each(res, function(index, value){
                var $row = $("<tr>" +
                    "<td>" + value.title + "</td>"+
                    "<td>" + value.author_name + "</td>"+
                    "<td>" + value.likes + "</td>"+
                    "<td>" + value.created + "</td>"+
                    "<td>" +
                    "<a href='/components/topics/" + value.id + "' class='mini ui black buttons' id='detail_check'>check</a>"+
                    "</td>"+
                    "</tr>");
                $row.find('.mini.ui.black.buttons').on('click',somefunction);
                $('#topics_list_table > tbody:last').
                append($row);
            });
        }
```

Or, if it's the same function for every such link, just add it using [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/):

```
$('#topics_list_table').on('click', '.mini.ui.black.buttons', somefunction);
```

Comment: thanks for you answer, but do you know why doesn't the style class="mini ui black buttons" show? is it the problem related to the sequence problem?

Comment: and also another problem is, when i try $row.find('.mini.ui.black.buttons').on('click',somefunction); replace the somefunction to function(){alert('hello')}; it occured error "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function "

Comment: The JS error is because I forgot to make `$row` a jQuery object -- my bad. Updated answer. Don't think I can help you with the first question.

Comment: However, I just noticed that you're adding `id='detail_check'` in multiple places, which is a no-no -- IDs need to be unique. You can change it to `"id='detail_check_"+value.id+"'"` and that might work.